# Count String Values in a Numeric Column Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe:

```
    Name    Hours_Worked
1   James   3
2   Sam     2.5
3   Billy   T
4   Sarah   A
5   Felix   5
```

1st how do I count the number of rows in which I have non-numeric values?

2nd how do I filter to identify the rows that contain non-numeric values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`s and create mask by [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Hours_Worked'], errors='coerce').isna()
#oldier pandas versions
#mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Hours_Worked'], errors='coerce').isnull()
```

Then count `True`s values by `sum`:

```
a = mask.sum()
print (a)
2
```

And filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
    Name Hours_Worked
3  Billy            T
4  Sarah            A
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Hours_Worked, dtype: bool
```

Another way for check numeric:

```
def check_num(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return False        
    except ValueError:
        return True

mask = df['Hours_Worked'].apply(check_num)
```

Comment: Why does `df.Hours_Worked.str.isnumeric()` doesn't work here?

Comment: @RafaelC - Because floats, it working only with integers.

Comment: Thought `isnumeric()` would work with floats too, Nice :)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. This does fit the bill for what I need. I kind of don't want to blanket change all my string to NaN, since I want to know why string is there to determine if I want it for something else. Your code will help me identify these lines better then I currently knew.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day I did this to kind of evaluate string in my numeric column:

```
df['Hr_String'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Hours_Worked'], errors='coerce')
```

I wanted it in a new column so I could filter and could a little more fluid for me:

```
df[df['Hr_String'].isnull()]
```

It returns:

```
    Name    Hours_Worked    Hr_String
2   Billy   T               NaN
3   Sarah   A               NaN
```

I then did

```
df['Hr_String'].isnull().sum()
```

It returns:

2

Then I wanted the percentage of total rows so I did this:

```
teststr['Hr_String'].isnull().sum() / teststr.shape[0]
```

It returns:

0.4

Overall this approach worked for me it helped me understand what string values are messing with my numeric column and allows me to see the percentage which if it was really small I may just drop the rows for my analysis. If the percentage was large, I'd have to figure out if I can impute them or figure something else out for them.